# Android - Listview ignores TouchEvent

Tags: android, listview

I have a `ListView` containing `RelativeLayout`-Items with `Text`, `Buttons` and stuff. I want to react on the user clicking on the button, but for some reason, `onItemClick` is not fired

Do you have any ideas what this could be caused by?

```
storeItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.st_storeitems);
storeItems.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
   @Override 
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long arg3)
   {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();     
         if(v.getId() == R.id.csi_buy) {
             // Some Code
         }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

you can either add

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

to the root/top layout on your ListView's row or

add the following properties

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

to the buttons, in  the ListView row item. That's the cause that prevents `onItemClick` to be invoked. Also you should avoid things like

```
 if (v.getId() == R.id.csi_buy)
```

inside `onItemClick`, because the view returned is row, not the item you clicked on. To mange view's click you should use `View.OnClickListener`

Comment: could also use `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to the root element in xml

Comment: @Raghunandan I never used it. Any side effects?

Comment: don't think there are any sides effects. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#attr_android:descendantFocusability

Comment: After playing around a bit, I went with @Raghunandan´s answer - works fine - but thanks for the tip that the whole row is returned